# How to inject dependency into existing controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have this controller that is defined on the body element:

```
app.controller('bodyController', ['$injection1', '$injection2',
    function($injection1, $injection2){
        // doing stuff here
}]);
```

Now somewhere else, I want to be able to inject another dependency into this controller. Pseudo-code:

```
app.controller('bodyController').inject(['$injection3', function($injection3){
    // doming more stuff here
});
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

You could inject `$injector` dependency inside controller & then inside a controller you can directly ask for other dependency in it.

```
app.controller('bodyController', ['$injection1', '$injection2', '$injector',
    function($injection1, $injection2, $injector){
      var injectorGet = $injector.get;
      //myService will be singleton instance of myService
      var myService = injectorGet('myService');
      //and injectorGet which you can get other dependency too.
}]);
```

Comment: OP says *somewhere else*. I think this can't be then answer. Because in this case why not simply injecting `myService` in the first place?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati what I understood from question is, OP wants to add/access 3rd(other) dependency, which he wanted to add later(this is what I assumed), let see what OP wants.. he will comment on it.. correct me if I'm missing anything. Though thanks for heads up.. :)

Comment: @PankajParkar, What do I do?I mean injection service elsewhere?

Comment: I mean injection service elsewhere? Why don't be injected at first?

Comment: @SSH because OP wanted to get dependency object dynamically, there might be a case with OP, where sometimes he might have added `service/factory` in app module, based on some condition in controller using `$injector` dependency (The reason I haven't added in DI array is, it will throw an error when dependency isn't there module)

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks for your answer. +1